# How to get data-value from radio input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple from which consists by inputs like that:

```
<form id='some-form'>
    ....
    <input type="radio" data-type="4" data-value="25" data-id="68" name="req-68">
    ....
</form>
```

I'm trying to loop through this form and get data values:

```
$('#some-form').filter(':input').each(function (i, element) {
     console.log(element.value);
     console.log(element.attr('data-value'));
}
```

`element.value` holds value '**on**' or '**off**' depending radio is chosen or not and it works properly but when I try to call `element.attr('data-value')` it throws an error.

So how can I extract **data-value** in this loop?

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe it's not a jQuery `element`, try with `element.getAttribute('data-value')` in that case.

Comment: Since it's a data element, you don't even need the getAttribute method.  You can just use the dataset off of the element.

Comment: IE10 and below only allows access using `HTMLElement.prototype.getAttribute()`. https://caniuse.com/#search=dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) instead of [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

The former will get you the elements *inside* the form, the latter will filter all elements `$('#some-form')` will provide.

HIH

**EDIT**

as pointed out by [gaetanoM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3880585/gaetanom) and [connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo), there is also the issue of using `element.attr()` without the `$()` which you will need since `.attr()` is a method of jQuery, not JS

```js
$('#some-form').children(':input').each(function (i, element) {
     console.log(element.value);
     console.log($(element).attr('data-value'));
     //
     // or
     //
     // console.log(element.dataset.value);
})

console.log('end');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='some-form'>
    
    <input type="radio" data-type="4" data-value="25" data-id="68" name="req-68">
    
</form>
```

Comment: You don't name the problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't elaborate on that, though.

Comment: @connexo, actually the problem is not `$(element)`, it's, as stated at the beginning of the answer, the use of `.filter()` instead of `.children()`. the `$(element)` part is just an additional fix which I noticed only because it threw such a big error at me from the beginning I'm surprised it was still there

Comment: @gaetanoM, please read my previous comment before editing away

Comment: *element.value holds value 'on' or 'off' depending radio is chosen or not and it works properly but when I try to call element.attr('data-value') it throws an error* it worked for OP with `element.value`, only `element.attr()` gave him an error.

Comment: `$('#some-form').children(':input')` can be shortened to `$('#some-form :input')` and the result is no different from `$('#some-form').filter(':input')`

Comment: @connexo, true, only I focused in the, in my opinion, more important problem in the question: *So how can I extract data-value in this loop? *, as I said, the `$(element)` part was throwing obvious error, the `.filter()` instead of `.children()` part was a silent assassin

Comment: @connexo, regarding your last comment: ... and the OP was properly warned of it, also regarding your last comment, it would have sufficed as an edit to improve the answer, but instead you shifted focus entirely to an easier-to-fix part of the scenario

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `.each()` function `element` is a regular `HTMLElement`, **not** a jQuery object.

Either wrap that using `$(element)` (or even `$(this)`) which allows to use
jQuery's `$.attr()`

```
$(element).attr('data-value')
```

or, even better, use the corresponding native DOM Api method

```
element.getAttribute('data-value'))
```

Since you are accessing a `data-` attribute, the DOM Api has a special object `dataset` to access these (from IE 11 upwards):

```
element.dataset.value
```

In case you have a name for your data-attribute like `data-cmon-lets-go` you can access it using camelcase notation:

```
element.dataset.cmonLetsGo
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use newer **jQuery >= 1.4.3**
You can use like this.

```
$(this).data("value");
```

**OR**

```
$(this).data().value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done with vanilla javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#some-form input[type="radio"]').forEach(radio => {
  console.log(radio.value, radio.dataset.value);
});
```

```html
<form id='some-form'>
    <input type="radio" data-type="4" data-value="25" data-id="68" name="req-68">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the each loop you are actually  in the context of the radio element so you can use `$(this).attr('data-value')` and it will work. The following is a working code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id='some-form'>
        <input type="radio" data-type="4" data-value="25" data-id="68" name="req-68">Hello

    </form>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#some-form :input').each(function (i, element) {

     console.log(i);
     console.log("element", element);
     console.log($(this).val());
     console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
   });
});
</script>
```